# Deploy and Run SSIS package on server using batch file

Tags: ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have created SSIS package on my local machine using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012 and it is working properly. Now I want to deploy it on Server and Run the package using a batch file on the server

So can you please provide steps on how to deploy and then Run it using a batch file on a server

Comment: If you deploy from SQL Server Management UI, at the end of the wizard you have the choice to export as sql script the whole deployment process.

Comment: Why use a batch file? I'd rather create a SQL Server Agent Job to run the package.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a batch file using the dtexec.exe command line tool.

Eg create a text file:

```
<dir of dtexec>/dtexec /F<dir of Package>/package.dtsx
```

Save as a Batch (.BAT) file.

Answer (score 0):

Edit below command to update package path and package name. Copy the modified code to notepad and save as .bat file and your batch file is ready.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /File "PackagePath\PackageName.dtsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem has been solved...
the actual problem of getting this **Error: 2018-08-30 07:37:43.57 Code: 0x00000001 Source: Script Task Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. End Error** was on server Renci.SshNet is not working..

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server 2017 you can go to:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\DTExecUI.exe"

And then run this. If you saved the file locally, then choose file system and then wherever the .dtsx file is saved(or you can simply go to the .dtsx file and double click on it)

If you saved it on the server, type in the server name and type of authentication with the user name/password if needed and then browse for the package and select it.

Then click the "Execute" Button. Done.

Check to see if there is a UI version of the DTExec on 2012.